# What is a good model structure for a WPF and EF application?

Tags: .net, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

Short question: Is there a best practice to setting up a single Model to handle both the lazy loading features of EF and also the interface sync of any background data changes for WPF?

Longer explanation/question (and my current solution):

There are plenty of articles explaining MVVM with WPF, and plenty of articles working with basic model classes and DBContext’s for EF, but none (that I’ve found) that tie the 2 together,

My application is a client-side WPF application which uses EF to persist the data generated by the application to a local SQLite database; there are background worker threads which the WPF application will fire off which returns data from other locations that require persisting, but that data will only be saved to the database if the threads complete and returns to the WPF application while its running - otherwise the results will be discarded and the app will try running the thread again next time,

Now I run into my problem….

EF requires Virtual ICollections for lazy loading (which I require) but in order ensure that the background data syncs with what is displaying on the WPF applications, I need to use ObservableCollections and implement the INotifyPropertyChange interface as well for other fields - so for example - say I have a Customer class which has a collection of Purchases within it, in order to accommodate both EF and WPF requirements, I would need Purchases represented as both an Virtual ICollection and an ObservableCollection,

My question is around is there a best practice for this to keep a single, unified model that supports both EF and WPF?

My current approach is to have 2 models - a “working” ViewModel and a “persisted” Model.

The working model has the same data as the persisted model, but the working model sits in the ViewModel of the WPF application - and has the data collections as ObservableCollections, with all the notify code hooked up to it, and also the Business Logic (followed a nice article [here](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) ). The persistence model is made up of POCOs and has all the collections as Virtual ICollections for lazy loading and has no other job to do other than work with EF. When the application is loaded up, within the App.xaml.cs file, I load what I need from the “persisted” model from SQLite into the “working” ViewModel for WPF and then let the application do its thing - then load any additional persisted data into the working ViewModel as required.

I look forward to your thoughts/other solutions.

Thanks

---

I don’t blog, but I’m sure there is the bare bones of a blog post in this!

Another solution that has just come to me, might be to scrap EF altogether as it doesn't neatly fit into this design - maybe just a custom data persistence layer instead.

It’s probably worth noting that my application isn’t massive spanning 100s of model classes, there are maybe going to be around 10 when its completed, so this does work for my situation - but I always like to prevent myself having to do extra work if I can - and learn new things - I looked briefly at [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) for weaving the INotifyPropertyChange elements into the Model, but hit some issues with .NET 4.6 so backed that out - I have enough moving parts at the moment without trying to deal with understanding and debugging someone else’s code.

Comment: I would recommend the **Repository and Unit of Work Pattern**, although I can't find a decent article, it has been mentioned a few times on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36523/unit-of-work-with-generic-repository-pattern-mvvm).

Comment: Thanks Mike, I had heard of those patterns when learning EF on Pluralsight, but hadn't thought about just abstracting the patterns away from EF. It's a shame that the 2 technologies don't link together in a better way, but I suppose they have different requirements. I'll maybe post an answer to myself once I start to code it up.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I'm currently working on an MVVM WPF application with an EF database, using the Repository and Unit of Work pattern. Using the unit of work pattern makes things a lot easier to separate the business logic and data layers.

Comment: Yeah it appears I did misunderstand. I understand the concept of Repository and UoW patterns, but as per the lengthier part of my question - I am struggling to conceptualise the Model class that works with ObservableCollections and ICollections, as well as using the INotifyPropertyChange. Do you have a sample snippet of code from a model class that you have where you are handling collections of objects for both EF and WPF?